# manage session timeout for Iframe and parent window

Tags: java, iframe, session-timeout

I have a Iframe java based web application, In which there is navigation from which user select some site and that get opened in iframe. Site is getting opened SSO (Single Sign On).

I have to manage session timeout for parent application and application opened in iframe .

How to do that?